# Как сделать чтобы код работал только с первым числом из переменной?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Есть переменная (id_code = 49808270244). Программа должна работать только с первым числом (т.е. с 4 в данном случае).

[image: описание в задаче]

мой вопрос о

Comment: int(str(id_code)[0])

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть в виде текста, а не изображения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самым простым способом "отпилить" от числа первую цифру - это превратить его в текст и взять первый символ:

можно явно через преобразование типов `int(str(id_code)[0])` как указали вам в комментарии, но можно еще и через универсальную функцию `format`:

```
print int(format(id_code)[0])
# 4
```

Другие способы это математически определить первую цифру через разрядность. Но чтобы определить разрядность рандомного числа нужно по-потеть, поэтому этот вариант слишком длинный.

Answer (score 2):

Выделение левых разрядов (чтобы убрать 4 правых, делим на `10**4`):

```
123456789 // 10000 = 12345
```

Выделение правых разрядов (два разряда - `10**2`):

```
12345 % 100 = 45
```

Comment: Проблема с отрицательными числами. `-12345 // 100 = -124` и `-12345 % 100 = 55`

Comment: @Lecron Это легко решается проверкой знака. Об отрицательных автор не упоминал, у него, похоже, жёсткий формат (кстати, для них и строковый подход напрямую не работает)

Answer (score 2):

Это уже ваш второй вопрос, а оба ваши вопросы бы автоматически исчезли, когда бы вы выбрали правильный подход. **Является вашей системной ошибкой, что в переменной** `id_code` **у вас появилось число, а не строка.**

Например из комментарий в вашей программе вытекает, что первая цифра может быть **тоже `0`** - но когда в вашей переменной `id_code` число, а **не строка**, `0` просто *исчезнет*.

Тем более, что вы эту переменную *не используете в арифметических операциях* - вас интересуют только **индивидуальные части этого 11-местного кода**.

Пока не будет в переменной `id_code` строка вместо числа, вы *постоянно будете с ней иметь не нужные проблемы*.

Постарайтесь, чтобы это была строка, а вы можете просто использовать отрезки - например первый символ будет `id_code[0]`.

Comment: Эта переменная и так задаётся как строчное выражение, в коде.

Comment: @Aleksandr, тогда почему вы нам представляете её как число - `id_code = 49808270244` - а не как *строку* - `id_code = '49808270244'`?

Comment: извиняюсь, я новенький в программирование, только начался первый курс

Comment: @Aleksandr, не надо извиняться, мы вам хотим помочь. Когда это строка, а не число, так ответ будет так как я написал: `id_code[0]`.А длина строки - это касается вашего предыдущего вопроса - будет просто `len(id_code)`, так что вы можете просто игнорировать сложные решения обоих ваших  вопросов.

Comment: а если мне нужно использовать сразу 2 числа 1 и 2?

Comment: @Aleksandr, тогда используйте отрезок - когда у вас `id_code = '49808270244'`, то `id_code[0:2]` будет `49` -  `[0:2]` значит: от позиции 0 включительно до позиции 2 не включительно.